# Openvpn on Android: Doesn't appear to be routing through tunnel

Tags: openvpn

I just noticed that my Android (running CM11) is not correctly routing my traffic to my openvpn server. I noticed when I was looking at the current connections on my OpenWRT router that I could see the VPN's local IP address, and the remote connection! It looks like this:

```
IPV4    TCP 10.9.0.20:56657 157.166.xx.xx:80
```

I could see all this in Luci's connection graphs, which means that OpenVPN is not sending my traffic over the tunnel at all, despite the reports from sites like [ipleak.net](http://ipleak.net) . This means that when I connect over mobile data, my carrier can likely see all of my traffic. This is not what I want, I am having a hard time fixing it.

I tried two different OpenVPN frontends, tweaking the firewall on the phone (afwall+) and also playing around with the 'redirect-gateway' directives. I am not sure if this a DNS leak or total disobiedience on Android's part of my routing rules. The fact that I can see these connections from the router makes me think that the traffic is not even being encrypted before it's sent over the internet. Any ideas or advice?

Server Config:

```
mode server
tls-server
local x.x.x.x
port 35777
proto udp
dev tun0
ca /etc/openvpnca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/randomcn.crt
key /etc/openvpn/randomcn.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh.pem
topology p2p
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
;topology subnet

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-config-dir clients
;client-to-client 
keepalive 7 80
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/ta.key 0
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
max-clients 3
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
```

log openvpn.log

In my client directory, I have these settings. On my PC I do not have this IP leak problem despite the settings being the same:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
```

I have dnscrypt running with unbound on the server, serving the clients. This configuration works on my PC, but it seems no matter what I do I still can see the vpn local IP and all of my remote connections with Luci on openwrt.

I have tried using both OpenVPN connect, Openvpn for Android, and I am currently trying to use the ICS binary as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research, I realized that either my ROM was corrupt or infected with malware, so I started from scratch, factory wiped my phone and installed a new ROM. The problem has been resolved. You should *never* be able to see openvpn connections on the local network. If you are, chances are that something is wrong. Since it is so easy to simply reflash a phone, I figured I may as well take this opportunity to upgrade to lollipop.